# 64-bit java won't allocate more than 2GB of heap memory

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

I'm running my program from eclipse and using 64-bit java, but I still can't get it to allocate more than 2GB of memory.  I'm running some benchmarks so I need a lot of memory.

I have this in my eclipse.ini:
-Xmx8g

I want it to use all my memory.
Could this be due to a 32-bit version of eclipse? I'm not sure what I have for eclipse.

I've tried sending in 
-Xmx8g
to VMArgs when running the program.
I'm running 64-bit windows 7 and a 64-bit JRE.

Comment: run the program from command line!

Comment: You are setting the max heap size for Eclipse, not for the program itself.

Comment: How can I run it from the command line while increasing the heap size?

Comment: Have you checked the path to the Java VM in the `eclipse.ini`?  By default it points to the 32bit version of Java.  Look for the `-vm` tag and see what it's set to.

Comment: There is no path to java in my eclipse.ini

Comment: What VM are you using? Some of them do have built-in maximums

Comment: Version 7 Update 17 from oracle.com

Comment: I forgot to mention, java version is HotSpot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying everything else, it looked like VMArguments were simply not working in eclipse.

Changing the DEFAULT VM args within eclipse worked (finally!):

Inserting VM arguments into your JRE: while Eclipse is open, open up Preferences (for Windows: located under Window menu item. for Mac: located under Eclipse menu item), open the Java section, click on Installed JREs, click on the JRE being used (probably will be jre6), click on the Edit... button, and insert this into the Default VM Arguments:

-Xms256M -Xmx8192M

Comment: I have the same problem; but I still get this problem and the error is this:
`Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096M`

`The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.`

Answer (score 6):

In the run configuration screen, go to Arguments tab, add `-Xmx8g` to the VM arguments text box.

Comment: I tried this, it still seems to cap at 2GB. System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") is returning 64.

Comment: You have to create a run config, and run your program from that, then the changes would be effective.

Comment: Are you filling up the entire 2GB as of now? If not, the JVM may not go to the 8GB level.

Comment: Yup, then getting the exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Also, Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() is returning less than 2 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")
```

And see if it returns 32 or 64 inside your program

Also you need to add -Xmx to your launch params for your program not just for eclipse.

You can verify your program's -Xmx is configured properly by doing:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Comment: Yup, it's 64 bit. How do I add -Xmx for other programs than eclipse?

Comment: It is a command line option.  So add it to the `java` command line.  If you are launching the programs from Eclipse, you can set the JVM command options from the launcher config; e.g. via the "Run > Run Configurations" Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-d64` option to the`eclipse.ini`