# Unable to save a dataframe to parquet using Pyspark

Tags: java, python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe generated from pyspark SQL query and when I tried to save it using the following code

```
mydata.write.mode('overwrite').parquet("file:///mypath/master")
```

I found the error as attached at the end.

Since the dataframe include Struct type (using mydata.PrintSchema):

```
result: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mycol1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- mycol2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Not sure if this is related to the data type or connection or something else, is there any way to help resolve it? Thank you!

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o658.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:677)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:567)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 52.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 52.0 (TID 1514, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:164)
26 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
33 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:823)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:164)
26 more
```

Comment: BTW spark set up is like ```spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()```

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

```
df.write.option("schema",write_schema).parquet(savepath)
```

Comment: Thank you, but it raised another error ```Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o627.parquet.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187904/py4jjavaerror-an-error-occurred-while-calling-o26-parquet-reading-parquet-fil

Comment: I check my java and the version is 1.8, seems to be another causes

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the reason of this issue, which stems from the JVM memory setup. Following the procedure of this post could help configure the setup of the JVM and all works

[64-bit java won't allocate more than 2GB of heap memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799476/64-bit-java-wont-allocate-more-than-2gb-of-heap-memory)